# Oracle to Big Query Tables

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-data

I am new to big query and learning it. I have a requirement where I'll have to load close to 300 tables from oracle source to Big Query staging tables. what is the recommended way to load the data? I know I can use dataflow for that but do I have to create 300 dataflow tasks for it or create single job to iterate it? Please share your experience and different ways to do it. Thanks a lot.

Regards,
Venkat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience , we wanted to migrate our data warehouse into bigquery , I didn't use dataflow or any tool
I just exported the tables into csv files and then used python code to iterate over the file and upload them into bigquery
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#python

or you can upload them into gcs and then into bigquery
if it's a daily operation
I think it's easier to maintain a single code that iterate over a list of tables extract them and append them into bigquery tables than creating 300 tasks

**update:**

example code for reading data from oracle to bigquery using pandas-gbq:

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('oracle://user:password@host_or_scan_address:1521/ORACLE_SERVIVE_NAME')

results = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name', engine,chunk_size= 5000)
if_exists = 'append' # or replace
schema = [] #specify bq_schema here if you don't want the autodetect schema
for result in results:
     result.to_gbq(destination_table='dataset_id.table_id', project_id='project-id',
                        table_schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists)
```

you can delete the chunk_size argument if you want to load the data as one chunk but this might consume the memory if the table is big

```
results = pd.read_sql('select * from table_name')
if_exists = 'append' # or replace
schema = [] #specify bq_schema here if you don't want the autodetect schema
results.to_gbq(destination_table='dataset_id.table_id', project_id='project-id',
                        table_schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for your answer but how do you export data into csv file? do you write any code? but in order to export into files, you still require onprimise server is it?

Comment: Also, how and where did you execute python code to load int BQ tables?

Comment: is it a one time thing or it will be a daily operation?

Comment: its basically a datawarehouse solution so its a daily process

Comment: if it's on daily basis, you can use a python code to get the data from your oracle database into CSV and then upload to bigquery, or directly from oracle to memory to bigquery, I use cloud composer with kuberenetes pod operator to execute similar daily operations

Comment: Do you have any python example or reference documents/websites to do the same activity? please let me know.

Comment: I added a python code example in the answer, this is to get data into dataframe then directly into bigquery using pandas-gbq package

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to extract the Oracle table content in files (CSV format for example). Copy the file into Cloud Storage. Then you load them into BigQuery.

- If you have data cleaning to perform, you can run a SQL query into the raw data loaded and store the result into a new table.
- If you have to repeat this, [trigger a Cloud Function which load the file into BigQuery, on Google Cloud Storage event](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). You can also create [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) for running data cleaning.

Dataflow is useless (expensive, less efficient, take more time) if the transformation that you want to do can be done is SQL.

However, if you need to request external API (for data transformation, such as ML API for example) or if you want to sink the data in another database than BigQuery (Firestore, BigTable, Cloud SQL,...), dataflow is the right tool

**EDIT**

To go deeper in detail, I assume that the tables are in the same dataset. Then, the code is simple

```
def hello_gcs_generic(data, context):

    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = 'my_dataset'

    bucket = data['bucket']
    path = data['name']

    table_name = path[path.rfind('/')+1:path.rfind(('.'))]

    dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=True,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
            type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
            field="date"  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        ),
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    )

    uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket,path)

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, dataset_ref.table(table_name), job_config=job_config
    )  # API request
    print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))
    
    load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
    print("Job finished.")
```

here the Cloud Functions is called on each file drops in the bucket. Therefore, if you drop 300 file in the same time, 300 functions will be triggered and the process will be performed in parallel.

Several points:

- The Table name is equal to the file name.
- By default, the behavior is a write-append (add the data to the table.
- I strongly recommend you to partition your table on a field, here a date field.
- The load job is often quick. If it take more than 9 minutes, use Cloud Run (limit to 15 minutes) or don't wait the end of the load ( delete this `load_job.result()`)
- The CSV start with 1 leading row. Not mandatory but in case of schema auto-detection, that help for naming the column nicely.

*note: I assume that all the file dropped into Cloud Storage have to be integrated into BigQuery. If not, you can add filter as describe in [one of my articles](https://medium.com/google-cloud/pubsub-message-filter-small-feature-for-big-improvements-3d2d690b94a2)*

Comment: hello, by any chance is there a detailed example of how to use cloud function to load file into Big Query? Also I see that cloud function can run only max of 9 minutes. If I have 300 tables to load, how can I use cloud function to iterate? any suggestions please.

Comment: how do you export data into csv file? do you write any code? but in order to export into files, you still require on-primise server is it?

Comment: I added a python example. If you prefer in other language, tell me.

Comment: In my previous company, the CSV file was created by an app (ridiculous simple), but yes it requires On premise processing. Except if you can reach your database from Google Cloud (through VPN for example). After the file generation, a cron sent all the files to Google Storage.

Comment: Do I need to create a trigger to run job?

Comment: No, when you put a file into Cloud Storage, and event is created. It's this event that trigger your Cloud Function